# drupal 8 field ui entity tabs not working

Tags: drupal, tabs, entity, drupal-8

i defined custom entity and defined field_ui_base_route in annotation to activate field ui .
the problem is the field ui tabs don't appear on base route page but only after visiting them manually in address bar .

field_ui_base_route is portal_admin.office_overview

```
portal_admin.office_overview:
  path: '/admin/portal/org/office'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Portal organization'
    _entity_list: 'portal_office'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer portal'
```

in links.task.yml i have default task :

```
portal_admin.office_overview:
  route_name: portal_admin.office_overview
  title: Overview
  base_route: portal_admin.office_overview
```

when i manually visit /admin/portal/org/office/fields i do see all tabs .
[image: field ui tabs]

but when clicking main tab Overview the tabs don't appear .
[image: overview page]

strangely when i do striped down example not related to entities and field ui the tabs do work :

```
mod1.page5:
  title: 'Main'
  route_name: mod1.page5
  base_route: mod1.page5

mod1.page51:
  title: 'sub1'
  route_name: mod1.page51
  base_route: mod1.page5

mod1.page52:
  title: 'sub2'
  route_name: mod1.page52
  base_route: mod1.page5
```

[image: striped down example]

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed .

i defined the entity routes to be generated automatically using AdminHtmlRouteProvider
but also defined the path for entity.portal_office.collection manually as route portal_admin.office_overview
so this is why the route portal_admin.office_overview has local task while the route entity.portal_office.collection did not and the tabs did not appear because the route entity.portal_office.collection prevailed over portal_admin.office_overview .